equivalence of definitions of angular momentum in $R^2$
everyone.
Basic question. I am reading Hall's book Quantum Theory for Mathematicians. In the section on classical mechanics, he gives two definitions of angular momentum in the plane. For momentum $p=(p_1,p_2)$ and position $x=(x_1,x_2)$, the angular momentum is defined to be the scalar quantity $J:=x_1p_2-x_2p_1$. Then, he says that a more geometrical definition would be the usual (in my experience) $J=\lvert x\lvert \lvert p\lvert sin(\theta)$. I imagine the two should be equivalent. I tried to show the equivalence using the standard definition of projection based on inner product $J=\lvert x\lvert \lvert p\lvert sin(\theta)=\lvert x\lvert \lvert p\lvert \frac{\lvert p-\langle x,p \rangle \frac{ x}{\lvert x \lvert } \lvert}{\lvert p \lvert}$. Developping this, I just can't arrive at an expression equal to $J:=x_1p_2-x_2p_1$. I usually make a lot of mistakes in developping algebraic expressions. Maybe it is just a dumb error. Could someone please help me.
Best,
Jeff.

$J$ is defined as a determinant:
$$J = \left|\begin{matrix} x_1&p_1\\x_2&p_2 \end{matrix}\right|.$$
It is well known that this determinant is the signed area of the parallelogram determined by the vectors $x$ and $p$.
We can see this directly: If $x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is a vector in the plane, let $x^\perp=\begin{bmatrix} -x_2\\x_1 \end{bmatrix}$ be the vector obtained by rotating it an angle of $\pi/2$ counterclockwise.
You can now note that
$$x_1p_2-x_2p_1 = x^\perp\cdot p = \|x^\perp\|\|p\|\cos\alpha = \|x\|\|p\|\cos(\pi/2-\theta) = \|x\|\|p\|\sin\theta,$$
where $\theta = \pi/2-\alpha$ is the angle between $x$ and $p$. (The angle between $x^\perp$ and $p$ is the complement of the angle between $x$ and $p$. Draw a sketch.)

Great. Everything is crystal clear. Thank you.

If $\vec p$ makes an angle $\theta$ with $\vec x$ and $\alpha$ with the positive x axis ...
$$\vec p = p(\cos \alpha, \sin\alpha), \;\vec x = x(\cos (\theta +\alpha), \sin (\theta +\alpha))$$
So...
$$x_1p_2-x_2p_1=xp( \sin (\theta +\alpha)\cos\alpha  - \cos (\theta +\alpha) \sin\alpha ) \\ = xp\sin\theta$$
